# White block in menu in IE9 and newer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a website and have an issue with IE9 and newer. The site has a left fixed menu that in Chrome, Firefox and Safari are attached to the left border of the window. In IE9 and newer it puts a white block between the window border and the menu.

The site can be found here: http://www.madogrejser.dk

I cannot figure out how to get rid of this white block. Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards,
Søren

Comment: please post the code here....scanning a url for css bug is bit tedious and unhelpful for future visitors!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be this:

```
media="all"
@media (min-width: 1230px)
body nav.clearfix ul.nav {
display: table-caption;
}
```

If you disable that `display` property the box disappears in IE.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you very much, you just saved my ass